# Can we use pyqt threads in nuitka or cython?

Tags: python, pyqt, cython, python-multithreading, nuitka

I know both **nuitka** and **cython** is problematic with python threads because of gil.

Some explained [here](https://lbolla.info/python-threads-cython-gil) can be used in **cython** `with nogil` but i couldnt find any example within **nuitka** or with qt threads.

Anyone has experience about it?

Comment: What is the problem with cython and `nogil`?

Comment: As you can see there is no problem with cython and nogil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`with nogil` works well with pyqt in **cython** but problematic in **nuitka** due to [here](http://nuitka.net/pages/differences.html)